# Free() Function in C of pointer to struct not compiling

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have implemented a linkedlist, and I am trying to create a function that starts at the head of the linkedlist and essentially stores the pointer to the struct in curr. It then uses free()...unfortunetly I keep getting

`LinkedList_Header(27343,0x1000dedc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x1007b42c0: pointer being freed was not allocated`

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* initialize(int input){
    struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = input;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void freeing(struct node* head){
    struct node* curr = head;
    while(curr->next != NULL){
        free(curr);
    }
    free(curr);
}
```

Comment: your curr is always the same  inside of the loop. you don't have _next_ for the loop

Comment: Set your code aside for a few minutes, then come back and read what you actually wrote, not what you *think* you wrote...

Comment: In a loop, as long as the current node isn't NULL, save the current node's "next" pointer, free the current node, then make the saved "next" be the new current node.

Comment: The error you quoted does not seem to be a compiler error. Next to "does not compile" that is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is the `freeing` function, which is incorrect. There are two possible ways for the function to fail.

Double Free

1. If the `head` of the linked list has a valid pointer on the `next` pointer, the freeing function will keep looping on the same initial pointer, which is the head. That will create a double free, thus you're freeing an unallocated pointer.

```c
//Would loop forever if it wasn't because of the double free.
//The loop never continues into the next pointer, and stays on the head.
struct node* curr = head;
while(curr->next != NULL){
     free(curr);
}
```

Never integrates through the linked list.

2. The second issue with your code is that the `while` loop will always iterate on the head, if it wasn't because of the double free, the loop would iterate forever.

The solution to issue 1 and 2 is to make the while loop iterate through the linked list correctly.

```
void freeing(struct node* head){
    struct node* curr = head;
    struct node* next;
    while(curr != NULL){
        next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}
```

The whole code with test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* initialize(int input){
    struct node* head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = input;
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void freeing(struct node* head){
    struct node* curr = head;
    struct node* next;
    while(curr != NULL){
        next = curr->next;
        printf("Freeing: %d\n", curr->data);
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node* a = initialize(23);
    a->next = initialize(42);
    freeing(a);
}
```

This is the output, now the code avoids double free and iterates correctly.

```
Freeing: 23
Freeing: 42
```